# Scope of a feature "..connected together"

Tags: claims

I guess this question relates to [General and specific feature](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/24298/general-and-specific-feature).
In the patent [EP 2778 117](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/047912842/publication/EP2778117A1?q=ep2778117) there is written in [0018]:

> "The outer layer (1) can be made of single material, such as leather,
> or plurality of material, such as leather, cotton or other types of
> material, such as leather, cotton or other types of material
> intertwined or connected together."

I wonder whether "..or connected together" includes "woven" material?
In case "..or connected together" involves every textile manufacturing, then I guess one does not have to specify or to describe any process like intertwined or the like? That's why it makes me think "..or connected together" does not include "woven" but on the other hand, what else would it include?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a cursory review of the patent, I'm figuring a woven fabric would constitute a single layer even if it were a blend of fabric fibers. In a woven fabric each individual fiber is hardly considered a "layer". The term intertwined might mean sewn together. I'm guessing a careful reading of the specification would clarify this. The whole patent seems to be about bonding two or more layers together.

Comment: I have understood it such that it is about how a single layer is constructed (woven, intertwined,..)? When only one manufacturing method is given, would the term "..or connected together" include "woven"? Does woven material include twines that are connected together?